# How to make a GET URL request (same server)

Tags: node.js, express

I'm running an express 4 app (nodejs)

In one of the server side functions, I want to make a GET request to get some value. The GET request url is pointing at the same server. Why this doesn't work and how do I make it work?

Extra info:

- http://mywebsite/ is the main domain of my web app.
- http://mywebsite/abc/getData/16-10-2017 works in the browser
- Externally facing requests work fine (so no issue with request setup)

  ```
  function testing(){
    dateVAL="16-10-2017"
    var requestURL = "http://mywebsite/abc/getData/" + dateVAL  


    request({
        url: requestURL,
        method:"GET",
    },
    function(error,response,body){
      console.log("error")
      console.log(error)
      console.log("response")
      console.log(response)
      console.log("body")
      console.log(body)
    });
  }
  ```

Error code:

```
 { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mywebsite mywebsite:80
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'mywebsite',
  host: 'mywebsite',
  port: 80 }
```

Comment: getaddrinfo is a DNS issue, are you making test in local with etc/hosts/ (or something similar) modification? or are you running on a live server?

Comment: live, production server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, modified my address from:

`var requestURL = "http://mywebsite/abc/getData/" + dateVAL`

to:

`var requestURL = "http://localhost/abc/getData/" + dateVAL`